# how to fetch variables list of tf.layers

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I want to apply gradient on the specified variables of one layer. So requires variable list to pass as argument:var_list into optimizer.minimize  .But I don't know how to fetch them.

such as:

```
a = tf.layers.conv2d(input, 3, 3, padding='same', name='a')
b = tf.layers.conv2d(a, 1, 3, padding='same', name='b')
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.pow(b-1,2))
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer()
train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss,var_list=???)
```

I just want to train the kernel variables, weight and bias
 of **layer b**,     and keep **layer a** untouched.

how can I do it. Or should I use lower level to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you want to train all the parameters of `layer b` (there are only weights and biases), but want to keep the parameters of `layer a` as it is (as you described), then you can pass `trainable=False` parameter to [`tf.layers.conv2d`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/layers/conv2d).

But if you want more control over the variables, you can manually select the variables to train after printing them with [`tf.trainable_variables()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/trainable_variables)

Comment: thank you .But actually,I have another optimizer2 to train on layer a. So trainable=False may not work. Is there convenient way to  make it?

Comment: You can get the variables list using `tf.trainable_variables` and supply the variables name you want to train to each optimizer